# Is lack of vectorized instructions for std::ranges::transform an issue with my expectations, the library, the optimizer, or the standard?

Tags: c++, vectorization, c++20

Consider the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> fn1(std::vector<int> u, std::vector<int> const& v) {
    std::transform(u.begin(), u.end(), v.begin(), u.begin(), std::plus<int>{});
    return u;
}
std::vector<int> fn2(std::vector<int> u, std::vector<int> const& v) {
    std::ranges::transform(u, v, u.begin(), std::plus<int>{});
    return u;
}
```

In gcc 12 -O3, `fn1` produces code that is vectorized, whereas `fn2` does not.  This difference can cause non-trivial performance implications.  I consider this a serious issue.  However, given the specification for `std::ranges::transform`, I cannot point to a specific defect.  In my opinion, it is borderline outrageous for "modern" C++ to have this performance caveat for `std::ranges::transform`.

Comment: btw, this happens in range/v3 as well.

Comment: Looking [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/transform), ranges transform is a lot more complicated then the [non-range version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).  That could easily make it "too complex" for the optimizer to optimize.

Comment: The first version is undefined if `v.size() < u.size()`. The second is not. If you make the second use `std::ranges::subrange(v.begin(), std::unreachable_sentinel)` the codegen looks equivalent.